# How to reach Kubernetes service from another computer?

Tags: networking, docker, kubernetes, coreos

My IP-address:

DNS_SERVICE_IP: 10.3.0.10
SERVICE_IP_RANGE 10.3.0.0/16

`kubectl get svc` return:

```
NAME           LABELS                                    SELECTOR                IP(S)        PORT(S)
guestbook      app=guestbook                             app=guestbook           10.3.0.72    3000/TCP
kubernetes     component=apiserver,provider=kubernetes   <none>                  10.3.0.1     443/TCP
mongodb        app=mongodb                               app=mongodb             10.3.0.223   27017/TCP
redis-master   app=redis,role=master                     app=redis,role=master   10.3.0.178   6379/TCP
```

Kubernetes master IP: 192.168.0.139
My local IP: 192.168.0.157

```
PING 10.3.0.223 (10.3.0.223) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.3.0.223 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7056ms
```

**How do I reach the service?**

Answer (score 0):

@mark.zupan suggested:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: devcenter-ui-green
  namespace: devcenter
  labels:
    name: devcenter-ui-green
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9000
    nodePort: 30011
  selector:
    name: devcenter-ui-green
```